# Renaming similarly named multiple columns in R quickly

Tags: r, rename

I have a set of 43 variables/columns named by default as X1, X2, X3.....X46 when I created the dataframe. I need to repace the X's with Q's. Is there a quicker way of doing this in R or must I use the rename() on each X individually? Please help, I want to learn efficient ways of accomplishing this! (I am a novice R programmer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
names(dataframe) <- gsub("X", "Q", names(dataframe), fixed = TRUE)
```

The `fixed = TRUE` makes it faster because you are not using actual regular expressions.

Comment: WOW that actually did it! Thanks so much! Can you add some information about the gsub function and how regex can also be used? It could be helpful in the future :)

Comment: You can type `?gsub` in R. Briefly, `gsub(search_regex, replacement_regex, string_to_make_replacements_on)`. Note it is vectorized, so you can do stuff like `gsub("X", "Q", c("MAX", "SIX"))` and it will turn into `c("MAQ", "SIQ")`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `cols` is the vector of column names, you can use `gsub` to substitute.

```
> cols
## [1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X6"  "X7"  "X8"  "X9"  "X10" "X11" "X12" "X13" "X14"
##[15] "X15" "X16" "X17" "X18" "X19" "X20" "X21" "X22" "X23" "X24" "X25" "X26" "X27" "X28"
##[29] "X29" "X30" "X31" "X32" "X33" "X34" "X35" "X36" "X37" "X38" "X39" "X40" "X41" "X42"
##[43] "X43" 

> gsub("X", "Q", cols)
## [1] "Q1"  "Q2"  "Q3"  "Q4"  "Q5"  "Q6"  "Q7"  "Q8"  "Q9"  "Q10" "Q11" "Q12" "Q13" "Q14"
##[15] "Q15" "Q16" "Q17" "Q18" "Q19" "Q20" "Q21" "Q22" "Q23" "Q24" "Q25" "Q26" "Q27" "Q28"
##[29] "Q29" "Q30" "Q31" "Q32" "Q33" "Q34" "Q35" "Q36" "Q37" "Q38" "Q39" "Q40" "Q41" "Q42"
##[43] "Q43"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe, e.g.

```
> df = data.frame(matrix(0,1,43))
```

you can first empty the current column names, and then name them with any wanted prefix, e.g. `"Q"`, using:

```
> colnames(df)=NULL
> colnames(df)=colnames(df, do.NULL=FALSE, prefix="Q")
```